# Add a calculated column based on same and two other columns in r

Tags: r

I'm trying to add a calculated column based on values of the same and another column calculated from the values in a third column.  There are three columns, *year*, *id*, and *value*.  If the *id* for 2011 matches the *id* for 2005, then subtract the *value* of 2005 from the *value* of 2011.  So the *difference* shows 10-11=-1, 20-5=15, and 30-16=14... and the remaining rows can be 0 or NA, it doesn't matter.  The following table shows the resulting table with the new *difference* column.

[image]

I know I could split the data into two tables and then create the column via a simple subtraction if the two tables are ordered the same by year and id, but that's not an option for this particular problem.  Tried thinking of how I could use case_when or ifelse but it's a mind-bender and can't get my head around it.  There are examples I've found but they don't address this - they're mostly based on using a comparison between only two columns, or perhaps three... here, though, one of the values is from the same column.  How can I address this?

Your help is appreciated greatly in advance.

Here is the code for the original table:

```
dat <- data.frame(year=c(2011,2011,2011,2005,2005,2005),
              id=c(1,2,3,1,2,3),
              value=c(10,20,30,11,5,6))
```

Comment: Yes, the data are for only two years, 2011 and 2005.  In this scenario the id does not repeat.  I do have another scenario where the id does repeat multiple times - but I wanted to start with the simple version.

Comment: What do you mean by `id` is not repeated? Are you trying to say for the same `year` and `id` you can have multiple values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrange the data based on descending order of `year` value and for each `id` subtract the current value with the next one.

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  arrange(desc(year)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(difference = value - lead(value)) %>%
  #to get 0 instead of NA use the below one
  #mutate(difference = value - lead(value, default = last(value))) %>%
  ungroup

#  year    id value difference
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
#1  2011     1    10         -1
#2  2011     2    20         15
#3  2011     3    30         24
#4  2005     1    11         NA
#5  2005     2     5         NA
#6  2005     3     6         NA
```

Comment: Perfect - thank you.  I'd never seen that before, using arrange and 'lead.'  wow.

Comment: If it were extended as you asked, where the data only have two years but now the id does repeat multiple times per year?  However, the value remains the same for each id within the same year.  Here is the code for the data:  `dat2 <- data.frame(year=c(2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,2005,2005,2005,2005,2005),
                  id=c(1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3,1,2),
                  value=c(10,20,30,10,20,11,5,6,11,5))`

Comment: I see that Phil has already shared an answer for that version.

Answer (score 2):

For situations where there are multiple ids in your comment to Ronak's answer, you can do:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

dat2 |> 
  pivot_wider(id, values_from = value, names_from = year) |> 
  unnest(c(`2011`, `2005`)) |> 
  mutate(difference = `2011` - `2005`) |> 
  pivot_longer(c(`2011`, `2005`), names_to = "year")

# A tibble: 10 x 4
      id difference year  value
   <dbl>      <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
 1     1         -1 2011     10
 2     1         -1 2005     11
 3     1         -1 2011     10
 4     1         -1 2005     11
 5     2         15 2011     20
 6     2         15 2005      5
 7     2         15 2011     20
 8     2         15 2005      5
 9     3         24 2011     30
10     3         24 2005      6
```